# Casting an alias template to the aliased type

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Consider this code:

```
struct foo {/* stuff */};

template <typename T>
using bar = foo;

// Elsewhere
bar<int> A;
auto &B = static_cast<foo&>(A);
```

Is using `B` legal?

Comment: I don't see any reason why not. `foo` and `bar<int>` name the same type. You don't even need a cast - just `foo& B = A;`, or `auto& B = A;`  [Demo](http://rextester.com/MIFCW3704)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. `bar<T>` is exactly the same type as `foo` for any `T`.